# Use custom SQL Server database with Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I have a requirement where I have a Client application i.e (MVC Application) and Identity Server 4 application where I need to authenticate the users from MVC application.

Now I am able to authenticate the In Memory static users as well as AspNetIdentity users with Identity Server 4.

But how can I use my custom database with Identity Server 4 to authenticate users.

e.g I have a table with following columns:

```
UserName, Password, Role, IsActive
```

I want to authenticate the users from this table with Identity Server 4.
Please help me out with this.

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Could you please provide any sample code regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much up to you how you do it. Your controllers responsible for handling the login interactions need to have the required dependencies injected into their instances. So you can imagine injecting your own `IUserService`, or `IUserRepository`, or `IUserStore` to do this. And then you can implement an `IProfileService` based off those interfaces as well.